# Selenium Browser keeps dying on me

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I see other people have been having this issue, by mine seems a bit different than anyone elses as it only is occuring when I run a full suite (fails on like test 20).

if I run a single test or only a few test, the code works just fine.

Otherwise, I get the following stack trace:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

I am running my code locally and I don't know why it doesn't try to create a new browser. Instead, it just skips all the remaining cucumber steps.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Here is my setup and teardown steps:

```java
public class Setup_Teardown_steps extends BaseStepClass {

    @Before("@selenium")
    public void selenium_before_step(Scenario scenario) { //Function responsible for setting the scenario start and global end condition
       //Selenium setup
       //initialize_selenium_elements();
       driver = WebDriver_Singleton.getNewDriver(); //Creates a new Webdriver instance.
       driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280, 800));


       startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       testData.ClearTestData(); //Clears saved test data
       testData.current_scenario = scenario;
   }


   /**
    * After each scenario Hook (except report scenarios) - public cause it has to be.
    */
   @After("@selenium")
   public void selenium_after_step(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
       endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       scenario.write("Run time = " + (endTime - startTime)/1000 + " seconds");

       if (scenario.isFailed()){
           String html_link = driver.getCurrentUrl();
           scenario.write("\n");
           scenario.write("URL = " + html_link);

           try {
               byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
               scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
           } catch (WebDriverException wde) {
               System.err.println(wde.getMessage());
           } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
               cce.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       driver.close(); //Clears cache and cookies
       testData.ClearTestData(); //Clears saved test data
   }
}

//WebDriver_Singleton Function below
private static WebDriver create_driver(){
    if (driver != null){
        driver.close();
    }

    assign_base_urls();

    String browser = System.getProperty("browser") == null ? "ff" : System.getProperty("browser");

    switch(browser.toLowerCase()){
        case "ff":
        case "firefox":
        case "mozilla":
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case "ie":
        case "internet explorer":
        case "internet_explorer":
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            break;
        case "chrome":
        case "google":
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Defaulting to Firefox browser");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicit_wait_timeouts, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(page_load_timeouts, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(script_timeouts, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return driver;
}
```

Comment: Share the code of `WebDriver_Singleton.getNewDriver();` and also...what version of Selenium? What browser? What version of that browser?

Comment: I am running 2.32.0 and using Firefox. Also I added the create webdriver function. Do you want the base class as well? I am creating my page classes there as well.

Comment: `if (driver != null){ driver.close(); }` What's this for? I am guessing this is the problem.

Comment: This is actually breaking again. I am now using selenium 2.33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the stack trace, was hard to find but the jenkins server was running out of memory.